# Split Observable into multiple Observables based on the index of the emitted item

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have an Observable/Flowable in RxJava and I want to create multiple Observables/Flowables based on the index of the emitted item.

So let's say I'd like to use 3 Observables. Then the first Observable should emit item 1, 4, 7, ... n-2, the second should emit item 2, 5, 8, ... n-1, etc. How would you achieve this?

[image: Split Observable based on the index of the emitted item]

Comment: You could use groupBy with modulo key or create 3 observables off of the source and filter them via the modulo key. (e.g., v % 3 and v % 3 == n )

Comment: Thanks! Then I should track the index of the actual emitted item somehow. Maybe I can constantly increase an AtomicInteger. Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, counting via AtomicInteger would be the simplest. A more involved solution would be zipping with a large range and using a record to hold the original value and the index.